# MPMoviePlayerViewController quits unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to get videos to play from my server on the iPhone device. I'm using the following method to do so, however, it only works in the simulator; and on my iPhone 4. It doesn't work on iPhone 3G?

If I call this method on the iPhone 3G, it opens the video modal screen, starts to load the video, and then closes the modal screen abruptly. No errors are shown in the console.

The iPhone 3G has version 4.0 installed. My iPhone 4 has version 4.1.

Has anyone else experienced this?

```
-(IBAction)playMedia{

NSString* url = [self.data objectForKey:@"url"];    

//initialize the movie player
self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

//show a background image while the user waits
moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;


//show the movie
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];

[moviePlayerViewController release];

}
```

Comment: Can you get the iPhone 3G with iOS 4 to play remote videos through other apps?  Several people (myself included) have had a lot of problems running iOS 4 on a 3G device.  If you're having stability problems in other apps, try rebooting the device and then try again?

Answer (score 1):

ok I got video to work on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 3G. Basically the issue was the file format. I was playing a .mov file. When I changed the format to .mp4, it now works on both devices. No change in code.

Hope this helps others with the same issue.

Comment: I changed it to a .m4v file with Quicktime, and it worked well. Open the video in QT10, click File->Save As, and select iPhone for the output. Then change the code to reflect the extension change. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the above a little differently:

```
-(IBAction)playMedia{ 

NSString* url = [self.data objectForKey:@"url"];     

//initialize the movie player 

MPMoviePlayerViewController *tmpPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
self.moviePlayerViewController = tmpPlayer; 

//show a background image while the user waits 
UIColor *tmpColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = tmpColor;

self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile; 

//show the movie 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerViewController]; 

[tmpPlayer release]; 
[tmpColor release];
}
```